# Grails Searchable plugin add to index condition

Tags: grails, searchable, compass-lucene

I have Domain :

```
class Listing {
  String name
  Address address
  static searchable = {
    address component: true
    only: ['name']
  }
  static constraints = {
    address nullable: true
  }
}
```

I want to have in search index only object with address !=null. Is it achievable by configuration?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question? -- If address is null then what does it matter if it is indexed or not?

Comment: in DB only 10% of listings with addresses. Also I dislike to filtrate result by query during search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene doesn't work that way. You can only search by fields and values that exist, and you cannot directly check if the field is present, SQL's "is null" check cannot be done here.
To implement what you need, you'll have to add something like `boolean addressPresent`, and set it to `true` if the address is filled up.
Then in your query you have to add additional clause to check the `addressPresent` field